# Symfony embed form ManyToOne relation

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to improve a personal application but I'm getting into trouble with an embed form. In fact, I have an advertType form in which I want to add a field in order to choose the skill and the level attached to the advert.

In that way, I have an advert entity, a skill entity, an advertSkill entity which is referencing advert and skill entities thanks to a OneToMany relation. The level attribute is from the advertSkill entity.

I don't know how to proceed to add a skill field in my advert form so as to the advert will be correctly stored with the corresponding skill and level.

There is no attribute in my advert entity which is referencing skill.

Below, a sample of my advertType class :

```
$builder
        ->add('date',       DateTimeType::class, array(
            'view_timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',  
            'with_seconds' => true              
        ))
        ->add('title',      TextType::class)
        ->add('content',    TextareaType::class)
        ->add('author',     TextType::class)
        ->add('email',      TextType::class)
        ->add('image',      ImageType::class)
        ->add('categories', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'             =>  'OCPlatformBundle:Category',
            'choice_label'      =>  'name',
            'multiple'          =>  true
        ))
        ->add('save',       SubmitType::class);
```

Thanks for help, I can give more details about my code but it's just ugly when I put some code with the .

Comment: Why a advertSkill entity? which properties does it have? what relations do you exactly have between all your entities?

Comment: AdvertSkill entity contains the following properties : id,level, advert (ManyToOne to the advert entity), skill (ManyToOne to the skill entity)

Skill entity contains : id, name

Advert entity contains : id, date, title, author, content, published, image, categories, applications, updatedAt, nbApplication, email, slug, ip, user

Answer (score 0):

I tried to go ahead reading some advices on the same problem as me on a french forum but I have got a mistake yet because I don't suceed in displaying my skills name and my levels name.

My AdvertType form class :

```
enter code here         $builder
        ->add('date',       DateTimeType::class, array(
            'view_timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',  // On affiche l'horaire avec le fuseau horaire de Paris
            'with_seconds' => true              // On ajoute les secondes àl'affichage de l'horaire
        ))
        ->add('title',      TextType::class)
        ->add('content',    TextareaType::class)
        ->add('author',     TextType::class)
        ->add('email',      TextType::class)
        ->add('image',      ImageType::class)
        ->add('categories', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'             =>  'OCPlatformBundle:Category',
            'choice_label'      =>  'name',
            'multiple'          =>  true
        ))
        ->add('advertSkill', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'        => AdvertSkillType::class
        ))
        ->add('save',       SubmitType::class);
```

My new AdvertType form class :

```
enter code here     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('advertSkill', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'                  =>  'OCPlatformBundle:Skill',
            'choice_label'           =>  'name'
        ))
        ->add('level', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'             =>  'OCPlatformBundle:AdvertSkill',
            'choices'           =>  array('Débutant', 'Intermédiaire', 'Expert')
        ));
}
```

Moreover, I added a OneToMany attribute "advertSkill" in the two classes referenced by the advertSkill class.

I don't understand how to make it works !